# Auto-refresh multiple JQueryUI dialog windows

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, refresh, chat

I'm working on a small chat application I need to do for a client's intranet system. I'm kinda novice in the JQuery and Ajax world but I'm trying my best. However, I'm facing a problem here that you guys might have the answer in the flick of a finger :)

I've made a Default.aspx page which has a user list and when you click on an hyperlink (a contact) on it, a new dialog window pops up and it shows, well, a chat window lol.

Thing is, something tells me I might be doing it wrong, I mean, it kinda works but not In The Right Way (tm).

What ticks me off is that I'm doing a "global" (?) ajax refresh on the whole page instead of having the contact list dialog refresh itself (dunno if I'm explaining myself correctly). Also, it doesn't feel right to add the chat windows that way inside the same jquery.

The root of the question is, how do I add a separate ajax call/function for each dialog window I spawn, in a less noobish way? (and also, how to? xD). The idea is to have the ajax call refresh the chat log for each window (so it shows old chat text and the new incoming messages).

Thanks in advance!

This is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

    // ############################
    // ############################

    $('#wndContacts').dialog({
        width: '150',
        height: '300',
        position: [20, 60]
    });

    // ##############################
    // ##############################

    function updateContacts() {
        $("#wndContacts").html('Loading..');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax/Contacts.aspx?token=<%= Session["token"] %>',
            timeout: 2000,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#wndContacts").html(data);
                window.setTimeout(updateContacts, 5000);

                $('.hContact').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var divID = "contact" + $(this).attr("href");
                    $(document.body).append(
                        "<div id='" + divID + "' title='" + $(this).attr("href") + "'>"
                        + "<div id='" + divID + "_chat'></div>"
                        + "<div id='" + divID + "_input' class='usrInput'>"
                        + "<input type='text' />"
                        + "</div>"
                        + "</div>"
                    );
                    $('#' + divID)
                        .dialog({
                            width: 200,
                            height: 300
                        });
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#wndContacts").html('Timeout contacting server..');
                window.setTimeout(updateContacts, 10000);
            }
        });
    }

    updateContacts();
});
```

Comment: No one? how does one bump in this site? :/

Comment: Hello? do I need to make a duplicate or something? >_>"